# update if exit and add new mysql ..

Tags: mysql

i got the following mysql query..I have tried many different format but cant seem to get this to work.
I got two tables. table mic.temp has  three columns while table products has quite a few.

I need to update values into table products from table mic.temp. The matching  column is model number.

i have written the following query but it updates all the field.I only need to update the  values found in temp table and also auto increment the product table.if a value is not found then insert it.I don't mind if non existent values in temp table are entered as null.

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO products(products_id, products_quantity, products_model, products_ean, products_image, products_price, products_date_added, products_last_modified, products_date_available, products_weight, products_status, products_tax_class_id, manufacturers_id, products_ordered, products_last_import, icecat_prodid, vendors_id, products_availability) 

  SELECT model, stock, price 
  FROM mic_temp 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  set  
  products.products_quantity = mic_temp.stock, 
  products.products_price= mic_temp.price');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
Update products join mic_temp on products.modelnumber=mic_temp.modelnumber set 
products.product_quantity=mic_temp.stock, products.product_price=mic_temp.price;
```

Specify all columns of mic_temp which you want to insert or update in products table under
  set statement.

Comment: hi. thanks for replying..i tried this and it doesn't update or insert existing/new products.